# If SRAS decreases, does nominal GDP increase or decrease?

Tags: macroeconomics

A decrease in SRAS would decrease real GDP, as producers would stop producing as much for whatever reason. This would also cause inflation, though. So what net effect does this have on nominal GDP? Is it indeterminate?

Answer (score 0):

It is indeterminate without any further information. You would have to know by how much did real output and inflation change to determine new nominal GDP level.